# Map reduce Started and it wasn't ending. mapreduce.job jobRunning job : job XXXXXXXXXXXX

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop2

I have created a runnable jar file and executing in Hadoop, I am not getting the Output. The code works fine. I have checked it in eclipse with adding hadoop jar files and I have got the Output absolutely right

[image]

```
hduser@Strawhats:~$ hadoop jar /home/hduser/Desktop/project.jar /user/hduser/input /user/hduser/output
17/02/20 19:18:04 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/02/20 19:18:04 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
17/02/20 19:18:04 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
17/02/20 19:18:05 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
17/02/20 19:18:05 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
17/02/20 19:18:05 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1487596891791_0003
17/02/20 19:18:06 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1487596891791_0003
17/02/20 19:18:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://Strawhats:8088/proxy/application_1487596891791_0003/
17/02/20 19:18:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1487596891791_0003
```

Comment: Looks like Resource manager is not able to allocate container for Application Master. Can you check the resource manager logs for errors?

Comment: I am new to it. Can u help me how to find it.Thanks

Comment: Logs will be in the `$HADOOP_HOME/logs` directory. Look for errors in yarn logs..

Comment: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.    in STDERR FILE